# Converting historical (1992/2000/2006) TIGER/Line files to modern shapefile formats

Tags: qgis, convert, tiger

I'm trying to get some historical geographic information from Wisconsin and have been pointed the way of the [TIGER/Line](https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/tiger-line.html) Shapefiles. Unfortunately, they're in a strange format (see, e.g., the files for [Adams County from 1992](ftp://ftp2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER1992/55/55001.zip) [.zip download link]), with file types like `.F5A` (a set of files of type `.F5{x}` where `{x}` is one of `A`, `I`, `P`, `R`, `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`, `6`, `7`, `8`).

This is quite foreign to me, but I've seen it suggested that it may be possible to convert these to modern shapefiles.

Is there a robust way of doing so? (It goes without saying I prefer a free option)

Alternatively, how could I open the file in a common GIS program (QGIS, SAGA, or R), whence I could convert it within those programs (or at least view the polygon boundaries, which is a step in the right direction)?

Comment: GDAL has TIGER driver http://www.gdal.org/drv_tiger.html which is also compiled by default. Have you tried to open your files as vector layer with QGIS?

Comment: @user30184 thanks, I'll check that out when I get to a machine. I've tried qgis but I'm not sure which file to select.

Answer (score 2):

GDAL has TIGER driver gdal.org/drv_tiger.html which is also compiled by default. You can simply open the Tiger files with QGIS with Add vector layer. Select all layers and you will see this:

[image: TIGER in QGIS]

Alternatively you can use GDAL command line utilities for converting TIGER data into other formats. Use ogrinfo for reading the list of layers (add -ro if you want to avoid the ERROR 4 message):

```
ogrinfo  TGR55001.F51
ERROR 4: Tiger Driver doesn't support update.
Had to open data source read-only.
INFO: Open of `TGR55001.F51'
      using driver `TIGER' successful.
1: CompleteChain (Line String)
2: AltName (None)
3: FeatureIds (None)
4: ZipCodes (None)
5: Landmarks (Point)
6: AreaLandmarks (None)
7: KeyFeatures (None)
8: Polygon (None)
9: EntityNames (Point)
10: IDHistory (None)
11: PolyChainLink (None)
12: SpatialMetadata (None)
13: PIP (Point)
14: TLIDRange (None)
15: ZipPlus4 (None)
```

Use ogr2ogr for converting layers into shapefiles. This command will create directory "output" which will contain a separate shapefile for each layer. The error message means that Shapefile format does not support all the integer list datatype that is used in some columns of TIGER data.

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" output TGR55001.F51
ERROR 6: Can't create fields of type IntegerList on shapefile layers.
```